# How to include SDL_ttf in pro file Qt Creator with SDL2.0

Tags: sdl, qt-creator, fedora, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to add a simple text to render it in a window. But I have a problem...

Everytime the console shows me the following answer :

```
"Couldn't load font file"
```

I don't know what is the origin of this problem. Maybe the mistake is in the .pro file :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL_ttf

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

There is the other part in main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

using namespace std;

void loop();

int main()
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "1" );
    SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" );

    if( TTF_Init() == -1 )
    {
        cout << TTF_GetError() << endl;
    }
    else {

        TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("lazy.ttf", 10);

        if( font == NULL ) {

            cout << TTF_GetError() << endl;

        }
        else {

            cout << "Font loaded" << endl;

        }
    }

    loop();

    return 0;
}

void loop() {

    bool quit(false);
    SDL_Event e;

    while( !quit ) {

        SDL_PollEvent(&e);

        switch( e.type ) {

        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Further informations:

- Fedora 20
- Qt Creator
- All the SDL packages installed with yum
- The ttf font in the same directory as the executable

Thank you in advance !

Comment: As you get a run time error from SDL_ttf it would suggest that the issue is not in the code, but rather that the font file isn't where it can be found. Check that it really is, and is named correctly (remember that file names are case-sensitive).

Comment: I checked again but nothing has changed and there is still this error. But I translated my code in SDL 1.2 and it works fine. The SDL 2 doesn't want to work with SDL_ttf... I don't know why... Any other idea ?

Comment: Check that you actually have the SDL2 version of SDL_ttf, a search for Fedora packages suggest that the rpm version might be 2.0.11, which is SDL_ttf 1.2. The 2.0 version is called 2.0.12.

Comment: Waw, it works ! Thank you !

For people who will have the same error, I removed SDL_ttf with yum and I installed the tar.gz version of SDL2_ttf-2.0.12 from this page : https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/

Then I modified the pro file like this :

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

INCLUDEPATH += usr/include/

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf

SOURCES += main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

To put the comments into an official answer:

This can happen if you link with `SDL_ttf` instead of `SDL2_ttf` on accident. The functions have identical names, so the call is made successfully, but the actions fail.

Make sure you linke with `SDL2_ttf` if using SDL 2.